# SQL 2005 Merge / concatenate multiple rows to one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

We have a bit of a SQL quandry. Say I have a results that look like this...

61E77D90-D53D-4E2E-A09E-9D6F012EB59C | A 
61E77D90-D53D-4E2E-A09E-9D6F012EB59C | B 
61E77D90-D53D-4E2E-A09E-9D6F012EB59C | C 
61E77D90-D53D-4E2E-A09E-9D6F012EB59C | D 
7ce953ca-a55b-4c55-a52c-9d6f012ea903 | E 
7ce953ca-a55b-4c55-a52c-9d6f012ea903 | F

is there a way I can group these results within SQL to return as

61E77D90-D53D-4E2E-A09E-9D6F012EB59C | A B C D  
7ce953ca-a55b-4c55-a52c-9d6f012ea903 | E F

Any ideas people?

Many thanks

Dave

Comment: You should be able to do it by combining STUFF() with ROW_COUNT().  I'm no TSQL expert, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to define a custom user-defined aggregate.  [Here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056.aspx) of a UDA which will accomplish something very close to what you're asking.

Why use a user-defined aggregate instead of a nested SELECT?  It's all about performance, and what you are willing to put up with.  For a small amount of elements, you can most certainly get away with a nested SELECT, but for large "n", you'll notice that the query plan essentially runs the nested SELECT once for every row in the output list.  This can be the kiss of death if you're talking about a large number of rows.  With a UDA, it's possible to aggregate these values in a single pass.

The tradeoff, of course, is that the UDA requires you to use the CLR to deploy it, and that's something not a lot of people do often.  In Oracle, this particular situation is a bit nicer as you can use PL/SQL [directly](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=215) to create your user-defined aggregate, but I digress...

Comment: Thanks, this was the best implementation for us.

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted; I've up-voted it because it seems as if it is a legitimate (and potentially elegant) solution that also answers the original question. @Dave – it would be useful (for others that find this question and its answers) to know *why* this was the best answer for you.

Comment: Thanks.  I expounded upon my answer.  Watch, now you'll downvote it ;-)

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
set nocount on;
declare @t table (id char(36), x char(1))
insert into @t (id, x)
select '61E77D90-D53D-4E2E-A09E-9D6F012EB59C' , 'A' union
select '61E77D90-D53D-4E2E-A09E-9D6F012EB59C' , 'B' union
select '61E77D90-D53D-4E2E-A09E-9D6F012EB59C' , 'C' union
select '61E77D90-D53D-4E2E-A09E-9D6F012EB59C' , 'D' union
select '7ce953ca-a55b-4c55-a52c-9d6f012ea903' , 'E' union
select '7ce953ca-a55b-4c55-a52c-9d6f012ea903' , 'F'
set nocount off

SELECT p1.id, 
          stuff(
                   (SELECT
                        ' ' + x
                        FROM @t p2
                        WHERE p2.id=p1.id
                        ORDER BY id, x
                        FOR XML PATH('') 
                   )
                   ,1,1, ''
               ) AS YourValues
      FROM @t p1
      GROUP BY id
```

OUTPUT:

```
id                                   YourValues
------------------------------------ --------------
61E77D90-D53D-4E2E-A09E-9D6F012EB59C A B C D
7ce953ca-a55b-4c55-a52c-9d6f012ea903 E F

(2 row(s) affected)
```

**EDIT**
based on OP's comment about this needing to run for an existing query, try this:

```
;WITH YourBugQuery AS
(
    --replace this with your own query
    select '61E77D90-D53D-4E2E-A09E-9D6F012EB59C' AS ColID , 'A' AS ColX 
    union select '61E77D90-D53D-4E2E-A09E-9D6F012EB59C' , 'B' 
    union select '61E77D90-D53D-4E2E-A09E-9D6F012EB59C' , 'C' 
    union select '61E77D90-D53D-4E2E-A09E-9D6F012EB59C' , 'D' 
    union select '7ce953ca-a55b-4c55-a52c-9d6f012ea903' , 'E' 
    union select '7ce953ca-a55b-4c55-a52c-9d6f012ea903' , 'F'

)
SELECT p1.ColID, 
          stuff(
                   (SELECT
                        ' ' + ColX
                        FROM YourBugQuery p2
                        WHERE p2.ColID=p1.ColID
                        ORDER BY ColID, ColX
                        FOR XML PATH('') 
                   )
                   ,1,1, ''
               ) AS YourValues
      FROM YourBugQuery p1
      GROUP BY ColID
```

this has the same results set as displayed above.

Comment: Thanks - but I should probably have pointed out that the results are from a SQL query, so I can't predict what the results will be be in order for me to union them row by row.

Comment: @Dave, in my example code I use all the UNIONs to just populate my table @t, they have nothing to do with the solution, just a way to get data into a table to query on.  I will edit the question to use a CTE, so you can make it work on any query (first example code worked on a table).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I used the aggregate function in the end as this will help us in other places. Have voted this up too though.

Comment: The nested subselect strikes me as being potentially very slow if you have a significant number of rows.

Comment: I loved this solution. Did what I needed very well. Adapted it to my complex query and it's working great. Had a problem .. and this solution helped me in about 10 mins. Thx a ton! Now I just have to break apart to see how it's working so I can build new solutions like this on my own. =)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is to use the FOR XML PATH option

```
SELECT
    [ID],
    (
        SELECT
            [Value] + ' '
        FROM
            [YourTable] [YourTable2]
        WHERE
            [YourTable2].[ID] = [YourTable].[ID]
        ORDER BY
            [Value]
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) [Values]
FROM
    [YourTable]
GROUP BY
    [YourTable].[ID]
```